# store into multiple document of single object nodejs

Tags: node.js, express

```
{
 "picture": [{"height": 500, "preview": "abc ", "url": "http://abc.jpg", "width": 375}, {"height": 500, "preview": "xyz ", "url": "http://xyz.jpg", "width": 375}],
 "user_id": "5fce2865cf6b77105413398",
 "mimetype" : "images/jpeg",
 "device_platform" : "ios"
}

let user = [];
for(let request of { ...req.body }) {
   
        let record = await new UserStatusModel({
            user_id: request.user_id,
            picture: request.picture,
            mimetype: request.mimetype,
            device_platform: request.device_platform
            
        }).save()
        user.push(record)
        
}
```

I have strange situation i want to store multiple document if there are multiple picture how to achieve this please gudie thanks

Comment: Yes, you need to use `.push()`

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek I have updated the question sorry for this, system was not allowing me to add more question

Comment: What's the issue?